# Spring boot data source auto configuration for PostgreSql failing

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, datasource

I am setting up a Springboot(version 2.0.4) project with maven build to use PostgreSQL database. I want to utilize data-source auto configuration feature of Springboot but it is giving me following errors:

```
Field dataSource in com.praveen.demo.MyController required a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be found.
Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType'
Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'javax.transaction.TransactionManager', 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType'
```

In my pom.xml I've dependencies on postgresql and HikariCP as below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Also I've in my application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb?user=myself&password=mypassword
```

In my Java file having @RestController annotation , I am injecting DataSource as below:

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
```

I am following below artcile: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html
I do not want to use JPA. I believe article is not suggesting to use the JPA for auto configuration to work.
I am expecting that Spring boot should auto-configure Data source for the application as I've declared the dependencies and provided the database URL. Still I get errors(as mentioned on top) on starting the application.

Edit-1: I am following below article:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html

Edit-2: Complete POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.praveen</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Although, I am still confused by the documentation provided at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html and was expecting that I should not be required to use JPA for auto-configuration to work if I am explicitly declaring a dependency on HikariCP and Postgresql. Closing it for now.

Comment: did you add <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId> ?

Comment: No I didn't add <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>. Can I not get the auto configuration without JPA? I was following below article: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html

Comment: The doc says Spring Boot can auto-configure embedded H2, HSQL, and Derby databases. "External" connections can also be auto-configured by using a pooling DataSource.

Comment: Section '29.1.2 Connection to a Production Database' covers non embedded database as well. and it says Production database connections can also be auto-configured by using a pooling DataSource

Comment: Exactly. If you use the spring-boot-starter-jdbc or spring-boot-starter-data-jpa “starters”, you automatically get a dependency to HikariCP

Comment: Question here is not how to get HikariCP. I am able to get HikariCP using explicit dependency declaration on HikariCP.  Article says 'If HikariCP is available, we always choose it.'. and I am making it available via dependencies. I do not want to use JPA. and  if I understood correctly, article is not suggesting to use JPA only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pom is fine if you don't want to use JPA.

Define `@Bean` for Datasource to configure or add property in `application.properties spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource`:

```
@Configuration
public class DbConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public HikariDataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }
}
```

also change your properties to below:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
spring.datasource.username-myself
spring.datasource.password= mypassword
```

Note: JPA configure for you everything so if not using JPA then you need to configure DataSource by telling about Hikari.

As per reference document [29.1.2 Connection to a Production Database](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database)

> If you use the spring-boot-starter-jdbc or
>   spring-boot-starter-data-jpa “starters”, you automatically get a
>   dependency to HikariCP.
>
> You can bypass that algorithm completely and specify the connection
>   pool to use by setting the spring.datasource.type property. This is
>   especially important if you run your application in a Tomcat
>   container, as tomcat-jdbc is provided by default.
>
> [Tip] Additional connection pools can always be configured manually.
>   If you define your own DataSource bean, auto-configuration does not
>   occur.

Comment: Removing above dependency did not help. I think it is indeed required. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html

Comment: and you have JPA dependency, can you please show me your complete pom??

Comment: can you please also change your properties as I updated in answer.

Comment: Update my question with complete POM

Comment: and I do not want to use JPA. I believe https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html is not asking that JPA is mandatory to use.

Comment: let me check, yes if not using jpa then hikari has to be added.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I am referring to Spring.io article:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html
Please refer section: 29.1.2 Connection to a Production Database. It says, We prefer HikariCP for its performance and concurrency. If HikariCP is available, we always choose it. 
So I am making HikariCP available via explicit dependency declaration. 
Can you refer me to some documentation where it says that I must use JPA for auto configuration to work

Comment: in same section see line: If you use the spring-boot-starter-jdbc or spring-boot-starter-data-jpa “starters”, you automatically get a dependency to HikariCP. so you have to add jdbc or jpa dependencies to order to configure hikari auto or you need to configure @Bean.

Comment: If dont want to define configuration then spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource adding property as you will see in my config I just told it to type, same as given 29.1.2 section.

Comment: Although, I am still confused by the documentation provided at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html and was expecting that I should not be required to use JPA for auto-configuration to work if I am explicitly declaring a dependency on HikariCP and Postgresql. Closing it for now.

Comment: Defining the Bean worked for me, setting the datasource.type didn't.